# Подскажите форум из семейства Stackoverflow по железу

Tags: windows, железо, процессор

Хочу выбрать процессор - Intel или AMD (склоняюсь к Intel, к примеру https://www.eldorado.ru/cat/detail/noutbuk-huawei-matebook-d15-i5-1155g7-16-512-space-gray-bode-wfh9/?show=response#customTabAnchor), нужно подробнейшее описание процессоров. Подскажите форум из семейства Stackoverflow по железу. Я искал - [Железо](https://www.google.ru/search?q=stack%20overflow%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE&newwindow=1&sca_esv=567788707&sxsrf=AM9HkKkeVFt-g66Q1UOoARgLIXsZ7hrLjQ%3A1695448470221&ei=ln0OZeaVDai_wPAPqZyzqA8&ved=0ahUKEwjmuLXehcCBAxWoHxAIHSnODPUQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=stack%20overflow%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiG3N0YWNrIG92ZXJmbG93INC20LXQu9C10LfQvjIFECEYoAEyBRAhGKABSKFFUOQLWOk_cAF4BJABAJgB_AGgAcwJqgEFMC43LjG4AQPIAQD4AQHCAgQQABhHwgIKEAAYgAQYFBiHAsICBRAAGIAE4gMEGAAgQYgGAZAGCA&sclient=gws-wiz-serp#ip=1), не нашел.

Comment: Stackoverflow - не форум, обсуждения здесь не приветствуются. Еcть же ixbt  и другие форумы

Comment: Такие вопросы (как выбрать сайт для вопроса) нужно задавать на https://meta.stackexchange.com/. Но что-то я сомневаюсь, что здесь есть подходящий.

Answer (score 0):

Список всех сайтов stackExchange есть на этой странице: https://stackexchange.com/sites . Stackoverflow - это только один из сайтов "семейства" stackExchange.

Я посмотрел все сайты - такого чтобы задать такой вопрос просто нет. Есть скажем "server fault", "computer science" или "lifehacks", но не стоит там задавать такой вопрос. Или как-то его кардинально переформулировать. И уж совсем точно - не надо приводить названий и ссылок каких-либо конкретных ноутбуков.

Соглашусь с комментарием что лучше выбрать ixbt или что-то подобное.